# Record and playback of all activity happened on fabric canvas

Tags: javascript, video, fabricjs, playback, recording

Can fabric keep track of event fired in canvas and related object(upon which event was fired ) in one big set (in short Recording of fabric canvas), so that by iterating over that set we can actually play back and show all activity performed on canvas.

Have a look at this:

link: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/record-and-playback-drawing-in-html5-canvas/

source: http://ramkulkarni.com/temp/2012-10-03/js/RecordableDrawing.js

demo: http://ramkulkarni.com/temp/2012-10-03/

I have made such a plugin like this, but only problem i had is about free drawing mode of fabric (I can get point on "mouse:up" but for that i have to get every property like style, strokewidth, color of point and store them along with point, which is very hard for me as of now!!).

So, can anyone look at link i have provided and replay whether is it possible or not?

Already had a look at [#1431](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1431) but this doesn't make sense.

***Edit:*** 
I want something like **"movie"** mode in this android app if you have tried it [***(Kids Doodle - Color & Draw)***](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doodlejoy.studio.kidsdoojoy&hl=en):

Comment: This https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/v1.4.13/src/mixins/canvas_events.mixin.js#L351 seems to be the place where I'd place the breakpoint to investigate what's stored where (e.g. what are the important properties of the `freeDrawingBrush` object) so that I could "_record_" it along with the timestamp. If I were you :)

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I have made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryv1ftt8/ - press "Enter drawing mode".

Comment: will be possible using state management check existing code for undo redo

Comment: @ptCoder I appreciate your work, but i'm not looking for only point coordinates. I have coded already to get coordinates but looking for all property for fabric point (has stroke width, color, size, transform etc.. means all property that have made by fabric on rendering of point. see at: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/dist/fabric.js#L7426-L7461